# Форма редактирования/создания рецепта

Tags: php, laravel

Хотел посоветоваться в решении такой задачи.

Есть html страница - это форма создания/редактирования рецепта.
Стал такой вопрос, как узнать, что пользователь хочет отредактировать существующий рецепт или создать новый (форма ведь одинаковая).

Есть такие варианты:

1. Это две кнопки на форме (Редактировать и Новый) - но этот вариант не сильно мне нравится.
2. При нажатие на кнопку сохранить, обратиться к базе и проверить есть ли там уже такой рецепт. Если нет, тогда создать или если есть, тогда обновить. - также не сильно мне нравится, так как в бд может быть такой рецепт, но с опечаткой при вводе. И получается, что пользователь добавит два одинаковых.

Может есть у кого-то идеи, буду благодарен за помощь :)

Comment: Вот я пользователь на вашем сайте. Я хочу добавить новый рецепт. Какую кнопку я буду нажимать: "Редактировать" или "Новый"? Вот я добавил рецепт на сайт, но допустил ошибку, какую кнопку я должен нажать: "Новый" или "Редактировать"? При редактировании записи, вы должны в форму выгрузить информацию, в том числе уникальный идентификатор рецепта. Так что путаница при редактировании исключена

Comment: Если хотите добавить новый рецепт, тогда кнопка Создать рецепт.
Если редактировать, тогда кнопка Редактировать.

Но форма одинаковая, что для редактирования, что для нового. Как потом, после заполнения или редактирования понять, что пользователь не добавлет новый рецепт, а редактирует например?

Comment: скрытое поле с идентификатором рецепта, который редактируют. Если его нет, значит это новый рецепт. Можно также передать скрытое поле `<input type=hidden name=action value=create>` или `<input type=hidden name=action value=update>`. В коде if'ом проверять какое из значений пришло

Comment: Спасибо за совет